# Whenever a user try to recover password or try to register I got mail delivery system error

Tags: 7, users, emails

Receiving Mail Delivery System error for almost every email generated by Drupal 7

What can be the reason?

here below the message from remote host

> SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
>      host p3nlsmtpcp-v01.prod.phx3.gdg [72.167.191.78]:
>      552 5.2.0 qo8J1p01B4NPGeA01 :: CPANEL :: **Message rejected for spam or virus content** ::
>      Please include this entire message when contacting support ::

Comment: Does the email include a lot of links, or capital letters? Whatever the reason, your emails are being blocked because they are appearing as spam. Try avoiding spam filters... http://mailchimp.com/resources/guides/how-to-avoid-spam-filters/html/